# SUMPRODUCT in VBA with multiple IF and FOR statements - ERRORS

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumproduct

I am trying to use the following `SUMPRODUCT` formula in VBA:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet 1'!$C$2:$C$10="OK"),(MONTH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=MONTH($B3))*(YEAR(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=YEAR($B3))*(MONTH(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)=MONTH(C$2))*(YEAR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10)=YEAR(C$2)))
```

My workbook is related to flight bookings and it consists of two sheets, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Specifically:

Sheet 1 includes the sample data:

```
| Booking date | Check-in date | Status |
|--------------|---------------|--------|
| 25-Sep-18    | 18-May-19     | OK     |
| 26-Sep-18    | 05-Jul-19     | OK     |
| 26-Sep-18    | 18-Jun-19     | OK     |
| 01-Oct-18    | 19-Jun-19     | OK     |
| 01-Oct-18    | 18-May-19     | OK     |
| 02-Oct-18    | 19-Apr-19     | OK     |
| 03-Oct-18    | 18-May-19     | CL     |
| 06-Oct-18    | 14-May-19     | CL     |
| 07-Oct-18    | 17-Jun-19     | OK     |
```

Whereas Sheet 2 includes the analysis output related to the `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

```
| Booking/Check-in | Apr-19 | May-19 | Jun-19 | Jul-19 |
|------------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Sep-18           |        | 1      | 1      | 1      |
| Oct-18           | 1      | 1      | 2      |        |
```

I fixed the Error '13' - Type mismatch by following both @Rosetta and @Foxfire And Burns And Burns suggestion. I also followed @JvdV suggestions to add Else. Now the code looks like this:

```
    Dim bk As Worksheet
    Set bk = Worksheets("Sheet 1")

    For Z = 2 To 3
        For j = 2 To 5
            For i = 2 To 10
        If bk.Cells(i, 3).Value = "OK" Then
        If Month(bk.Cells(i, 1)) = Month(Cells(Z, 1)) Then
        If Year(bk.Cells(i, 1)) = Year(Cells(Z, 1)) Then
        If Month(bk.Cells(i, 2)) = Month(Cells(1, j)) Then
        If Year(bk.Cells(i, 2)) = Year(Cells(1, j)) Then

        Range(Cells(j, Z)).Value = Range(Cells(j, Z)).Value + 1

Else Next i
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If

    Next j
    Next Z

    End Sub
```

Now I get the `Next without For` compile error. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *I keep on getting Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch.* Where? What line?

Comment: line 1: Dim bk as Worksheet,... no 's'

Comment: You have defined `bk` as `Worksheets`, a collection, not a single object. Later on you do `Set bk = Worksheets("Sheet 1")` so `bk` should be defined as `Worksheet`

Comment: Thank you both! The code has started running though Excel is not responding. In your opinion, the rest of the code seems ok?

Comment: You haven't declared your second worksheet. What would happen if a wrong sheet is active upon this line `If Month(bk.Cells(i, 1)) = Month(Cells(Z, 1)) Then` ?

Comment: @JvdV Hmm then Next i. Where should I integrate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `.Evaluate` to get the result from the `SUMPRODUCT` formula since you want to integrate the formula into VBA. I have rewriten some of your code to make it a bit more dynamic too. That way you can have a dynamic number of rows on sheet1, and a dynamic number of rows AND columns on sheet2. See the code below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc As Long, x As Long, y As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr1)
    Set rng2 = .Range("B2:B" & lr1)
    Set rng3 = .Range("C2:C" & lr1)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = 2 To lc
        For y = 2 To lr2
            .Cells(y, x).Value = .Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!" & rng3.Address & "=""OK""),((MONTH(Sheet1!" & rng1.Address & ")=" & Month(.Cells(y, 1)) & ")*(YEAR(Sheet1!" & rng1.Address & ")=" & Year(.Cells(y, 1)) & "))*((MONTH(Sheet1!" & rng2.Address & ")=" & Month(.Cells(1, x)) & ")*(YEAR(Sheet1!" & rng2.Address & ")=" & Year(.Cells(1, x)) & ")))")
        Next y
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

This would remove all these `For ... Next` loops apart from the dynamic loop through all rows and columns on sheet2.

I hope you understand what is going on. If you got question please feel free to ask. Make sure to adjust names of sheets accordingly!

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Works like a charm. Let me include some more parameters.